# Enabling carl9170 in xconfig

Tags: linux, compiling, wifi, cubieboard

I am building the sunxi-linux kernel for a cubieboard and I need the carl9170 driver to make a usb wifi adapter work. I am using the 3.4 sunxi kernel, and no matter what I do in xconfig, I cannot enable the option CONFIG_CARL9170 because it is greyed out. I tried satifying all of its dependcies, but it is still greyed out. How can I enable the carl9170 driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a long time, but I got it. After running make sun4i_defconfig run make menuconfig and enable wireless and then under wireless make sure CONFIG_80211 is enabled, its probably called mac80211 driver. Then go down to wireless lan and enable atheros wifi. Then finally it will allow you to enable the carl9170 driver. It will probably called something like ath9170 community driver. For some reason this changed the name of the kernel build to include dirty at the end, but it did not matter as it still worked for me.